# Filter by (unique) matching values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

With Ramda and

```
const data = [{
  "id": "a",
  "name": "A"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "name": "B"
}, {
  "id": "c",
  "name": "C"
}]
```

I can do

```
const findById = (id, data) => R.pipe(
  R.find(R.propEq('id', id))
)(data)

const id = "a"

findById(id, data) // => { "id": "a", "name": "A" }
```

but what about taking an array of id values to return a list with just the matching objects? I.e.

```
const ids = ["a", "c"]

const findByIds = (ids, data) => R.pipe(
  // ?
)(data)

findByIds(ids, data) // => [{"id": "a", "name": "A"}, {"id": "c", "name": "C"}]
```

Something like pluck, pick, etc, but for values instead of keys, where each value can be assumed unique.

(Preferring terse, maybe even point-free variants).

The closest I've gotten so far is exchanging the ? for either

```
  R.filter(x => R.contains(x.id, ids))
```

or

```
  R.takeWhile(x => R.contains(x.id, ids))
```

both yielding the A object.

Thanks! I'm pretty new to Ramda and the above is mostly how I use it, so any insights around that would be very welcome too.

*UPDATE*

This is a non-question. It actually works in the [REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.21.0#?code=const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22a%22%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22A%22%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22B%22%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22c%22%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22C%22%0A%7D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20findById%20%3D%20%28id%2C%20data%29%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.find%28R.propEq%28%27id%27%2C%20id%29%29%0A%29%28data%29%0A%0Aconst%20id%20%3D%20%22a%22%0A%0AfindById%28id%2C%20data%29%0A%0Aconst%20ids%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D%0A%0Aconst%20findByIds%20%3D%20%28ids%2C%20data%29%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.filter%28x%20%3D%3E%20R.contains%28x.id%2C%20ids%29%29%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20R.takeWhile%28x%20%3D%3E%20R.contains%28x.id%2C%20ids%29%29%0A%29%28data%29%0A%0AfindByIds%28ids%2C%20data%29) but not for tests in my local env (Atom + Wallaby + AVA). Not sure why but I'll update if I figure it out. See verified answer for variations using both a static and dynamic key. Would still be fun to hear of any other approaches.

*UPDATE 2*

Turns out it was just a typo. Maybe I should reconsider using complex hashes for test ID's. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Preferring terse, maybe even point-free variants).

This is the wrong objective. Prefer code that reads well and works. Coding is not a game where the shortest answer wins, except when [coding is a game where the shortest answer wins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If you want "golfed" code, you should be asking there.

Anyway, you pretty much gave the answer yourself.

```
var data = [{
  "id": "a",
  "name": "A"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "name": "B"
}, {
  "id": "c",
  "name": "C"
}];

const findByIds = R.curry((ids, data)=>
  R.filter(x=> R.contains(x.id, ids), data));

findByIds (['a', 'c']) (data);
//=> [{"id": "a", "name": "A"}, {"id": "c", "name": "C"}]
```

---

Maybe you'd like `"id"` to be a dynamic property

```
var data = [{
  "id": "a",
  "name": "A"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "name": "B"
}, {
  "id": "c",
  "name": "C"
}];

const findByProp = R.curry((prop, ids, data) =>
  R.filter(x=> R.contains(x[prop], ids), data));

findByProp ('id', ['a', 'c'], data);
//=> [{"id": "a", "name": "A"}, {"id": "c", "name": "C"}]
```

Comment: I totally agree about terse when it comes too much at the expense of clarity. Should've made that CLEAR! :) Thank you for the answer. Pointed me to the fact that it actually works in the REPL (added link above). Doesn't work locally (tests with Atom + Wallaby + AVA) for some reason. I'll update if I figure it out.

Comment: Are ES6 arrow funcitons supported in your environment?

Comment: Yeah ES6 is alright. Turns out it was just a typo. Maybe I should reconsider using complex hashes for test ID's. :D

Comment: I would also curry in the data parameter: `const findByProp = curry((prop, ids, data) => R.filter(x => R.contains(x[prop], ids), data));`

Comment: @ScottSauyet reasoning?

Comment: Just the flexibility.  You can then call it as `findByProp('id', ids, data)` or `findByProp('id')(id, data)` or `findByProp('id', ids)(data)` or `findByProp('id')(ids)(data)` as turns out to be most convenient.

Comment: And spot on about readability!  Points-free is great when it increases readability, as it sometimes can.  But it should never be a goal on its own.

Comment: @ScottSauyet ah I just figured Rambda's magical curry sauce would've bridge the gap. I personally write everything in manual curried so I'm used to writing/chaining my expressions without ever having to think about arity. Thanks for sharing this Rambda idiom.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks for sharing and explaining. Great to have in the context of a familiar problem when I get more into currying.